# How to change the name of an EXTJS 6 app

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd, extjs6

I want to rename my EXTJS 6 application but I don't know how to make it works. I tried to rename the folder, then replace all the occurences with the new one.
`sencha app refresh` works fine

```
sencha app build production
```

gives me

> [ERR]
>
> [ERR] BUILD FAILED [ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Failed
> to compress input
>
> [ERR]   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInst [ERR]
> ance(Unknown Source) [ERR]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I've found what the problem was : 
I wanted to rename my application as 'A-BC' but ExtJs doesn't support that format, use 'A_BC' instead